# Как перезагрузить страницу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть страница на которой имеЮтся блоки(много блоков), в которых я выбираю кол-во нажатием **плюсика и минуса**
таких блоков много, и они разбиты отдельным скриптом на группы и группы обьеденены своими div-ами, и все потом еще обернуто общим дивом "my_div".  
Вот тут оформил полнее картину https://jsfiddle.net/profy/urvksd67/24/
Вот отдельный блок

```
<div class="woosb-product" data-name="ЧТО-ТО" data-price="16" data-qty="0" data-order="1">
        <div class="woosb-thumb">
                <a class="woosq-btn no-ajaxy">                            <div class="woosb-thumb-ori">                                   </div>
    <div class="woosb-thumb-new"></div>
                </a>                                </div><!-- /woosb-thumb -->
        <div class="woosb-title">
                <div class="woosb-title-inner"><a class="woosq-btn no-ajaxy" >ЧТО-ТО ТИТЛ</a></div>
        <div class="woosb-availability"></div>                 </div>
   <div class="woosb-qty woosb-qty-plus-minus"><div class="woosb-qty-input"><div class="woosb-qty-input-minus">- (минус)</div>  
   <div class="quantity">
                <label class="screen-reader-text">Количество ЧТО-ТО</label>
        <input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="1000" name="quantity" value="0" title="Кол-во" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
      <span class="product-qty-arrows">
    <span class="product-qty-increase lnr-up"></span>
    <span class="product-qty-decrease lnr-down"></span>
        </span>
        </div>
    <div class="woosb-qty-input-plus">+ (плюс)</div></div>
  <!-- /woosb-qty-input -->
  </div>                                
 <div class="woosb-price">
     <div class="woosb-price-ori">
                <del>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">         <bdi>0.00&nbsp;
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">грн</span></bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>0.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">грн</span></bdi></span></ins>  
        </div>
   <div class="woosb-price-new"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Иногда возникает **необходимость** сбросить выбор количества т.е. обнулить выбор,

Единственное что я придумал это перезагрузить всю страницу полностью, тогда соответственно все обнулится.

Для этого использую.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.woosb-products').forEach(n => {
  n.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<button id="something" >Перезагрузить</button>');
});
$('#something').click(function() { location.reload();
});
```

В разметку могу добавлять элементы только скриптами.

МОЖНО ? сделать чтобы страница полностью не перезагружалась ПРИ КЛИКЕ, а

сделать "перезагрузку/сброс только нужного дива class="my_div" ?

Можно сбросить эти плюсы/минусы в исходное состояние, или обнулить, или в исходное состяние.?

Я задавал похожий вопрос, но оказалось что я был некорректен задавая его, теперь вот надеюсь расписал все подробненько без косяков.

И перезагрузка по клику.

Comment: По сути, вам надо просто input обнулять?

Comment: честно говоря, боюсь сказать да... или нет ... ???

Comment: [Так?](https://jsfiddle.net/9acgq35j/)

Comment: ..несовсем, сброс нужен для всего выбора, т.е. не под каждым блоком а одна кнопка сброса для всех блоков, мы повыбирали в одном блоке , другом ...пятом...а потом нам нужно сбросить ВО ВСЕХ блоках

Comment: [Тогда, так?](https://jsfiddle.net/g8t6afjk/)

Comment: дааа, спасибо большое